# 2 Recaptcha showing on news letter section

Tags: magento2

i eanble Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi from admin config and enable recaptcha for newsletter section but it showing 2 captcha i debug on code level its coming n_US/Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/template/reCaptcha.html when i remove code from this file both captcha disappeared

Expected result
only 1 captcha show

Actual result
2 captcha are showing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you or anyone that works in this project has added again the block of ReCaptcha in Subscribe Layout.
Or maybe the Javascript that render this template is call twisted